# RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same - PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to push both my mode and data, images and labels, to run on the GPU by doing:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Followed by:

```
count = 0
loss_list = []
iteration_list = []
accuracy_list = []
epochs = 30

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):
            net = net.to(device)
            images.to(device)
            labels.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            count += 1

            if count % 50 == 0:
                correct = 0
                total = 0

                for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(testloader):
                    images.to(device)
                    labels.to(device)

                    outputs = net(images)
                    predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)[1]
                    total += len(labels)
                    correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
                accuracy = 100 * correct / float(total)

                loss_list.append(loss.data)
                iteration_list.append(count)
                accuracy_list.append(accuracy)

                if count % 500 == 0:
                    print("Iteration: {} Loss: {} Accuracy: {} %".format(count, loss.data, accuracy))
```

I'm explicitly pushing my model and data to device however I am met by the error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-341-361b906da73d> in <module>()
     12 
     13             optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 14             outputs = net(images)
     15             loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     16             loss.backward()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    394                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    395         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 396                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    397 
    398     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

I feel like I'm doing the right thing by pushing both model and data to GPU but I can't figure out why it's not working. Does somebody know what's going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your weights are saved on your gpu but your input is on your cpu. You can change that by: `images.cuda()`

Comment: But images are already sent to device by these " images.to(device)" in the 9th line of the code

Comment: Im confused by my answer too. I mean it's not wrong, but it seems like is code already was right. Maybe he gave us the error message of another version of his code

Comment: Just going to add a comment here for people looking to solve the exact opposite problem (RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same). This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942810/runtimeerror-is-there-a-way-to-torch-loadmodel-pt-on-cpu helped me and there aren't really any direct references to it on similar threads.